# Why Unsafe.allocateInstance(Class.class) failed?

Tags: java, jvm, unsafe

I'm now using unsafe. When I run the following code:

```
unsafe.allocateInstance(Class.class)
```

There happen's

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: java.lang.Class
```

Since `Class` is a non-abstract class, why it so special? And is there any way to construct an 'empty' `Class` like `allocateInstance`?

Comment: Well `Class` is quite a special class. It's so close to the JVM that I don't find it surprising that even `Unsafe` can't handle it. What would an "empty" `Class` be after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is an explicit check inside HotSpot JVM to ensure that `java.lang.Class` cannot be instantiated through JNI, Unsafe etc. See [instanceKlass.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/aa4ffb1f30c9/src/share/vm/oops/instanceKlass.cpp#l1157):

```
void InstanceKlass::check_valid_for_instantiation(bool throwError, TRAPS) {
  if (is_interface() || is_abstract()) {
    ResourceMark rm(THREAD);
    THROW_MSG(throwError ? vmSymbols::java_lang_InstantiationError()
              : vmSymbols::java_lang_InstantiationException(), external_name());
  }
  if (this == SystemDictionary::Class_klass()) {
    ResourceMark rm(THREAD);
    THROW_MSG(throwError ? vmSymbols::java_lang_IllegalAccessError()
              : vmSymbols::java_lang_IllegalAccessException(), external_name());
  }
}
```

Such instance would not be valid anyway, so it does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I'm looking for. Now I can confirm only `Class` is special.