# Scala Reflection: instantiating a singleton object

Tags: scala, object, reflection, instantiation

I'm using the following code to instantiate a scala object. This works, but there seems to be one problem: the `println` is printed out *twice*, each time with another hashcode.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

object Test2 { println("init"+hashCode())}

val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val m = ru.typeOf[Test2.type].members.filter(_.isConstructor).head.asMethod
val m2 = mirror.reflectClass(typeOf[Test2.type].typeSymbol.asClass)
val cm = m2.reflectConstructor(m)
val e = cm.apply()
```

Results in:

```
init472467991
init2051378291
e: Any = Test2$@7a458c73
```

the `hashCode` of `e` is equal to the latter one (2051378291). I'm wondering why this is because as far as I know there should be only one?

EDIT: using scala version 2.12.4

Comment: please, provide information about Scala version

Comment: I agree with @greenshade. For version 2.11 I got: ```scala.ScalaReflectionException: object Test2 is an inner class, use reflectClass on an InstanceMirror to obtain its ClassMirror```

Comment: scala version 2.12.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## JVM has no singletons*

You're invoking a private constructor of a class. Scala reflection allows it. And when you invoke a constructor, you get a new instance back.

It's actually pretty hard to make a singleton in plain Java because there are ways to construct an instance except using `new Something`. For instance, de-serialization [might not call any constructors besides one of Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141440/how-are-constructors-called-during-serialization-and-deserialization). And there's `sun.misc.Unsafe#allocateInstance` that can conjure new instances of any class [sans `java.lang.Class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751715/why-unsafe-allocateinstanceclass-class-failed) without calling any constructor code.

Scala `object` does some job behind the hood to ensure you don't accidentally create a second instance during any normal usage (e.g. it hides the constructor and handles de-serialization), but it cannot protect you from *deliberately* creating one. When you start using reflection, you do exactly that.

Even Java `enum`s can be instantiated at runtime using reflection. You cannot call `Class#newInstance` on an enum directly (the implementation forbids it), but knowing a bit of internal details can get you there**

```
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption // first std enum I could remember for a quick dirty sample

val ctor = classOf[StandardOpenOption].getDeclaredConstructors.head

val aac = ctor.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("acquireConstructorAccessor")
aac.setAccessible(true) // unlimited power!

val ctorAccess = aac.invoke(ctor)
val newInstanceCall = ctorAccess.getClass.getDeclaredMethod("newInstance", classOf[Array[AnyRef]])
newInstanceCall.setAccessible(true)

// note that it does not throw ClassCastException, so it's a fine instance
val uhOh = newInstanceCall.invoke(ctorAccess, Array("UhOh", 42)).asInstanceOf[StandardOpenOption]
assert(uhOh.name == "UhOh")
assert(uhOh.ordinal == 42)
```

[(interactive version @ Scastie)](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bMiq9HN1QiCoVqynxGt0iw)

---

To get the "default" instance, you [can access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831580/how-to-call-the-object-method-not-class-method-using-reflection-in-scala?noredirect=1&lq=1) a public static field named `MODULE$` using reflection. You can also [run whole scala compiler at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46561577/scala-using-right-type-class-instance-for-reflected-runtime-instance/46563559#46563559)

It's likely to be the best bet for you to not rely on reflection in whatever you're trying to achieve.

---

BTW, it is possible to get `ScalaReflectionException` trying to run your code in IntelliJ worksheet or Scastie in worksheet mode, because these things wrap your code in another object with main method

---

* Only tested on few versions of HotSpot JVM

** Please don't do this in any serious code! I only use this to prove a point. This is also pretty useless because it does not change `values` or `valueOf`. And yes, I only checked it on HotSpot that comes with JDK8.

Comment: Creating a new `enum` instance is even simpler. Just get the `Constructor`, call `setAccessible(true)` on it and `unreflect` it to a `MethodHandle`. The check made in `newInstance` has been forgotten for the conversion (all versions from 7 to 9) and when calling `invokeExact`, there will be no check in principle. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34956094/2711488)…